# How to know what are the Unicode ranges are covered in webfont?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, unicode

How can I find out what Unicode ranges a webfont file (may be WOFF2, WOFF, TTF or EOT) covers?

For example I am analysing a latin font, is it possible to know what are the Unicode ranges of latin covered by it? Is there any tool available to analyze it?

Comment: Just a sidenote: With the latin blocks, it’s much more important which characters are covered than which characters aren’t. Except for *Basic Latin,* each of the Latin ranges contains at least one character that is deprecated or only for very exceptional uses (e.g., ¦ŉǱⱶꝚẜ). E.g., there is no reason for a font to fully cover *Latin-1 Supplement,* except for its own sake.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft my question here is , any given webfont, is there a way to see the unicode ranges it covered?

Comment: I understand that. I am just doubting that this is really what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You could install [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) - it's a free and open source font editor and will show you what glyphs the font has - it has various ways of laying out the code points in order.

[image: FontForge font information screenshot]

Note that coverage isn't as easy as looking at which blocks are fully covered.  For example, it's very common for a font to contain basically all of Latin-1 plus a small handful of characters from Latin-Extended-A/B in order to fully support languages like French, Hungarian, Catalan etc, see [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Languages_commonly_supported_but_with_incomplete_coverage).  You do NOT need most of Latin-Extended-A/B to cover most European languages, but you DO need more than what's in Latin-1 for many.

Comment: Unfortunately this simply displays ranges in which at least one glyph exists. For example, for a font file with just "A" in, FontForge will display `Basic Latin U+0020-U+007E 1/95`.

Comment: The two numbers at the end show this though. 1/95 means it contains 1 out of 95 characters in that range.

Comment: @thumasrutter: Yes but it doesn't help me. It just says that the `20-7E` range (95 possible glyphs) has only got 1 in there.

Answer (score 2):

There's a neat feature now in FontForge (see [@thomasrutter's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/62094/163150)) that lets you visually see all the glyphs in a given range, which helps when determining which unicode ranges that your font supports.

After opening the font with FontForge, click `Element` > `Font Info...` > `Unicode Ranges`. This will give you an overview of how many glyphs exist in a given range. For example, for me it says

```
Basic Latin  U+0020-U+007E 95/95
...
General Punctuation  U+2000-U+206F 85/111
...
```

meaning that I have all of the glyphs in Basic Latin (95/95) but only 85 out of the 111 glyphs in General Punctuation.

Now, to see **which** 85 glyphs, click the "General Punctuation" entry in the list. This should make your other window jump to and highlight them as seen in the image below.

[image: FontForge jumping to a given unicode range when it's clicked]

With this, it's easy to click the individual glyphs and figure out what ranges your font supports. In my case, it's U+2000-200B, U+2010-2027, and U+202F-205F in General Punctuation.

You would then have to do this for each of the ranges in the list.